# Angular error (in Euler angles) through quaternions

Tags: quaternions, orientation, robotics

I found this formula in some notes but I would like to have a reference (book, paper, etc.) to understand where it comes from. I know that it works only for small angles.

$
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_e\\
\theta_e\\
\psi_e
\end{bmatrix}
= sgn(q_e^0)
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
2q_e^1\\
2q_e^2\\
2q_e^3
\end{bmatrix}
$

- $q_c$ is the quaternion setpoint
- $q$ is the current quaternion (the one we are "measuring")
- $q_e=q_c \otimes q^{-1}$ is the error in the orientation
- While 
  $\begin{bmatrix}\phi_e\\ \theta_e\\ \psi_e \end{bmatrix}$ is a vector of error in roll, pitch, and yaw angles.

Thanks in advance for your help.